# Regex matching word that is in text 2 times

Tags: regex

I need match a word in English text that appears 2 times in the text. I tried

```
(^|\ )([^\ ][^\b]*\b).*\ \2\b
```

but this doesn't match all lines.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your regex. For example, `\b` word boundaries cannot be used in a character class, so `[^\b]*` will not work as intended.

You probably want something like

```
(?s)\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

This will match the entire text from the first occurrence of the word to the last. This might not be what you actually intended.

Another idea:

```
(?s)\b(\w+)\b.*?\b\1\b
```

This will match only the text from the first occurrence of the word to the next.

The problem with both these approaches is that for example in a text like

```
foo bar bar foo
```

the regex will match from `foo` to `foo`, blindly ignoring that there is a duplicate `bar` in-between.

So if you actually want to find all words that occur in duplicate, then use

```
(?s)\b(\w+)\b(?=.*?\b\1\b)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)       # Allow the dot to match newlines
\b(\w+)\b  # Match an entire word
(?=        # Assert that the following regex can be matched from here:
 .*?       #  Any number of characters
 \b\1\b    #  followed by the word that was previously captured
)          # End of lookahead
```